# Angular/RxJS: synchronous observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that has a method foo. Inside the method I subscribe to  an observable (http-client).

```
foo () : boolean
{
  let ret : false;

  this.http.get ("/blabla").subscribe (
  (resp) =>
  {
    ret = true;
  }

  return ret;
);
```

I like to return a boolean value from `foo()` that depends on the get. That is not working because `http.get` is asynchronous - return is called before `http.get` finished.

How can I make this synchronous?

Returning the observable instead boolean is not an option here.
That is because I handle the response of get in foo (not shown here) but I also need to act out of foo depending on its return.

---

I extended my sample with pipe and tap. Now I return the `http.get`-observable for outside the service and I process the `http.get`-result with tap.

```
foo () : Observable <any>
{
  return this.http.get ("/blabla").pipe (tap (x => handlehere ()));
}
```

As far I see, there is only one ugliness with it. I have the complexity of parsing the get-result inside AND outside of foo. I would prefer a simple boolean outside of foo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `How can I make this synchronous?` <= you don't, you return an observable or a promise. `Returning the observable instead boolean is not an option here` <= why?

Comment: Then you have no option because synchronous code could become asynchronous in one operation, but asynchronous code could never become synchronous again

Comment: `but I also need to act out of foo depending of its return` <= then make the acting on the call also occur asynchronously. Once you understand the pattern used for asynchronous javascript (typescript) code/interaction it will be much easier for you to write your application. There is generally a fair amount of asynchronous interaction in applications because they interact with external resources (user input, databases, network streams, etc). You will be a better programmer for it.

Comment: Returning an Observable would be also possible but then it must be related to http.get. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Follow along with the [Tour of heroe's](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) tutorial or read up on the [http client](https://angular.io/guide/http) documentation. Both are rich in examples of how to do just that.

Comment: your 2nd update looks good, stay on that direction

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This method can only run asynchronously, so you don't have a lot of option. Returning the observable and subscribe or return a promise. Perhaps returning a Promise will suit more your need in terms of comprehension.

In your service, the `foo()` method:

```
async foo() {
   const result = await this.http.get("/blabla").toPromise();
   
   // do what you want with result 

   return result;
}
```

How to call it:

```
this.myService.foo().then( (result) => {
   // Do what you want with the result
});
```

Comment: toPromise() is deprecated and will be removed in v8. Anyone found some simillar workaround?

Comment: You can use ` firstValueFrom(observable)` instead of toPromise()

Comment: this answer is not synchronous in angular.  firstValueFrom(observable) is also not synchronous, because you have to await both call's, which means other resources can do stuff while waiting on the result.

Answer (score 0):

In essence: How to call an asynchronous process synchronously. And though this question might be old, this tends to come up again and again, which is why it is still relevant.

And it turns out that you actually can make the transition from async to sync with a simple while-loop. Let me demonstrate this with a simple Promise:

```
function asyncToSync(promise)
{
  let finished = false;
  let returnValue = null;
  let error = null;

  promise
  .then(v => returnValue = v)
  .catch(e => error = e)
  .finally(() => finished = true);

  while(!finished) {
  }
  if(error != null){
    throw error;
  }

  return returnValue;
}
```

It should be noted that this is heavily discouraged because it makes your application block. I couldn't think of any good reason to do this. Any sync function that relies on the return value of an async function should be just used as or inside the callback function, like `promise.then(doSomethingSync);`

Comment: This solution is not working. JavaScript is monothreaded, so your while loop never gives the hand back to background processes, and thus the promise never resolve.